# makefile for two compilers

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to make a single `makefile` for two compilers. I like the example Intel has in its oneAPI, see below. Basically, under each target rule, it has explicit compilation rules. But my `makefile` is like:

```
# compile old fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# compile new fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# link everything
$(target): $(objects)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -I $(BLD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I saw that one way would be to change the `$(FC)` variable plus the flags to appropriate values in a target. The advantage of the Intel that one can very specifically change the additional switches so if for `gfortran` i have the line `$(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -I $(BLD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)` what if I need this to look like `$(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -J $(BLD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)` for ifort etc. Is there a way to make a rule within another rule so something that would look like:

```
GFORT_EXE = $(target).gfort
IFORT_EXE = $(target).ifort
#
gfort: $(GFORT_EXE)
ifort: $(IFORT_EXE)
$(GFORT_EXE):
    $(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    # compile new fortran files
    $(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    # link everything
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -I $(BLD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Or what is the best way to approach it if i need the command line to look different in principal for each compiler?

---

The intel `makefile`:

```
# Copyright Intel Corporation 2014
#
# To compile with the GNU* C/C++ compiler, creating an execution file with the
# extension ".gcc" for binary instrumentation, issue:
#
#   > make
#
# To compile with the Intel(R) C++ Compiler for Linux*, creating an execution
# file with the extension ".icc":
#
#   Source <path_to_compiler_bin>/compilervars.sh or iccvars.csh;
#
#   > make icc
#
# To compile with the Intel(R) C++ Compiler for Linux* with Intel(R) MKL library
# creating an executionfile with the extension ".mkl":
#
#   Source <path_to_compiler_bin>/compilervars.sh or iccvars.csh;
#
#   > make mkl
#
# To compile with the Intel(R) C++ Compiler for Linux to cross compile for the
# Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) coprocessor, creating an execution file with the
# extension ".mic":
#
#   Source <path_to_compiler_bin>/compilervars.sh intel64
#
#   > make mic
#
# To compile them all, use the source line from the Intel MIC architecture
# option above, then type:
#
#   > make all

SHELL = /bin/sh

PARAMODEL = -DUSE_THR   # Default parallelism using pthreads/Win threads
#PARAMODEL = -DUSE_OMP -fopenmp # Use OpenMP for multithreading

GCC     = gcc
ICC     = icc
CFLAGS  = -g -O3 -fno-asm
OPTFLAGS = -xSSE3 
# OPTFLAGS = -xHost -fno-alias
# add -DALIGNED to the multiply.c and matrix.c
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lm

GCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(PARAMODEL)
ICFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(PARAMODEL)-DICC -debug inline-debug-info #-vec-report3 -qopt-report -qopt-report-phase=vec
MKFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -DUSE_MKL   -DICC -mkl -debug inline-debug-info


GCC_EXE = matrix.gcc
ICC_EXE = matrix.icc
MKL_EXE = matrix.mkl


srcdir = ../src

gcc: $(GCC_EXE)
icc: $(ICC_EXE)
mkl: $(MKL_EXE)
all: $(GCC_EXE) $(ICC_EXE) $(MKL_EXE)


OBJS = util.o thrmodel.o multiply.o matrix.o 


matrix.gcc: $(srcdir)/matrix.c $(srcdir)/multiply.c $(srcdir)/multiply.h $(srcdir)/util.c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c
    $(GCC) $(GCFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/util.c -D_LINUX
    $(GCC) $(GCFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c -D_LINUX
    $(GCC) $(GCFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/multiply.c -D_LINUX
    $(GCC) $(GCFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/matrix.c -D_LINUX
    $(GCC) $(GCFLAGS) -g $(OBJS) -o ../matrix $(LDFLAGS)


matrix.icc: $(srcdir)/matrix.c $(srcdir)/multiply.c $(srcdir)/multiply.h $(srcdir)/util.c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c
    $(ICC) $(ICFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/util.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(ICFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(ICFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/multiply.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(ICFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/matrix.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(ICFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o ../matrix $(LDFLAGS)


matrix.mkl:     $(srcdir)/matrix.c $(srcdir)/multiply.c $(srcdir)/multiply.h $(srcdir)/util.c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c
    $(ICC) $(MKFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/util.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(MKFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/thrmodel.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(MKFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/multiply.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(MKFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) -c $(srcdir)/matrix.c -D_LINUX
    $(ICC) $(MKFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o ../matrix $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJS) $(GCC_EXE) $(ICC_EXE) $(MKL_EXE)

# * Other names and brands may be claimed as the property of others.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't redefine a rule within a rule (and quite frankly, you wouldn't want to, as there's tons of sharp sticks with this sort of approach, which you would be guaranteed to trip over).   I would suggest for something like this you do two separate output directories, and have the rules based on the output directory, as so:

```
objects := ...
FC_gfort := ...
FC_ifort := ...

$(BLD)/gfort/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC_gfort) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BLD)/gfort/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC_gfort) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BLD)/ifort/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC_ifort) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BLD)/ifort/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC_gfort) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# link everything
$(target).gfort: $(BLD)/gfort/$(objects)
    $(FC_gfort) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -J $(BLD)/gfort $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(target).ifort: $(BLD)/ifort/$(objects)
    $(FC_ifort) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) -I $(BLD)/ifort $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Now, if you have lots of rules, and this gets to repetitive, you can use a define and eval, as so instead:

```
LINK_FLAG_gfort:=-J
LINK_FLAG_ifort:=-I

define RULES_template =

$$(BLD)/$(1)/%.o: $$(SRC)/%.for
    $$(FC_$(1)) -c $$(FFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<

$$(BLD)/$(1)/%.o: $$(SRC)/%.f90
    $$(FC_$(1)) -c $$(FFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<

$$(target).$(1): $$(BLD)/$(1)/$$(objects)
    $$(FC_$(1)) -o $$@ $$(FFLAGS) $$(LINK_FLAG_$(1)) $$(BLD)/$(1) $^ $$(LDFLAGS)

endef

$(eval $(call RULES_template,ifort))
$(eval $(call RULES_template,gfort))
```

Note the double `$$`'s in here (but not in front of `$(1)`...)

Also, I mentioned sharp sticks with your original idea, where you override the rule -- say you build ifort, and then did a subsequent build of gfort, with no clean in between.   The .o files would not be rebuilt, as the timestamps would be newer than the sources', but the linker would run and use the obsolete artifacts.

Hope this helps